# How do I set up my PATH for Ruby and Rails?

Tags: ruby

Is there a known solution for this?

```
WARNING: You don't have /Users/user/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH, gem executables will not run.
```

I already added:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/Users/spirosgerokostas/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin"' >> ~/.bash_login
```

Comment: Shot in the dark, try exiting your console and opening it again.  The path won't update for that session until you login.  You could also run that command (without the echo, just the export) in your current shell and it may work.  If that doesn't work, then I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: Alternatively, try running `touch ~/.bash_login` instead of quitting and re-opening.

Comment: The warning says ruby1.8, but you're adding ruby2.0 to your path. Is this a typo? Also what GoGoCarl said.

Comment: you add the version 2.0 and the warning complains about the 1.8 version.

Comment: Check if the path is configured before you call the ruby

Comment: typo sorry WARNING:  You don't have /Users/user/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin in your PATH,
   gem executables will not run.

Comment: so you are using system's ruby? You would be better with ruby version manager like: chruby, rvm or rbenv

Comment: Append the output of `which ruby` and `gem env` to your question please.

Comment: `/Users/user/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin`makes no sense in context with `/Users/spirosgerokostas/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin` because the two paths are not the same. You're not showing us the full information about your Ruby set up; It appears you're using multiple Rubies because of `.gem/ruby/1.8` and `.gem/ruby/2.0.0`. You're on Mac OS, because only it uses `/Users`, so how did you install your Ruby 2.0? I don't think we can help you unless you give us a lot more information or someone gets a lucky shot in the dark.

Comment: check that .bash_login is actually being parsed with an echo, it might not be being parsed at all.